# mysql to javascript and adding days afterwards

Tags: javascript, mysql, timestamp

I am having issues adding days to a mysql date time. 
If you look at my code, I take a mysql datetime and I convert it into a javascript date. I then take another field and add days to the getDate(); value. Its not adding correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ProjectExtendDeadline').change(function(){
        var oldDate = $('#ProjectOldDeadline').val();
        var t = oldDate.split(/[- :]/);
        var days = $('#ProjectExtendDeadline').val();        
        var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]+days, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
        //d.setDate(d.getDate());
        month = d.getMonth();
        date = d.getDate();
        month = (month < 10 ? "0" + (month) : month);
        date = (date < 10 ? "0" + (date) : date);
        var date = d.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+date+" "+d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds();
        $('#ProjectNewDeadline').val(date);
    });
});
```

This is the values after the code has been ran

[image]

As you can see, the date does not change. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: "t[1]+days" adding days to months?? do not forget to convert strings to integers, otherwise this is concatenation

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish? It isn't very clear. Also, I have found it easier to deal with dates between MySQL and JavaScript by always dealing with milliseconds from epoch between the two. Use MySQL's UNIX_TIMESTAMP * 1000, and Date().getTime() in JavaScript to get the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var today       =new Date();
 var in_a_week   =new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+7);
```

ps: `t[1]+days` both are strings, not integers (and this is the sum of months and days??). It gives you concatenation of strings. Rewrite it (in general) as +t[1] + +days

And your code will look like:

```
// from your previous question - it SHOULD be like this or 
// your month will be incorrect
var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
d = new Date().setDate(d.getDate + +days); // here it could be just days

// add your 1 to output month number only here
month = d.getMonth() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your days to the months, actually. The Date() constructor is

```
new Date(year, mon, day, hour, min, sec)
```

and you're doing

```
new Date(year, mon+days, day, hour, min sec)
                  ^^^^^---oops?
```

Note that the your `date` is actually 2 years 5 months ahead of `olddate`, which is due to the addition your constructor actually being a string concatenation:

```
'03' + 2 -> '032' -> octal number -> 26 decimal = 2 years 4 months.
```

As well, remember that JS months are 0-based, so your MySQL date is actually 1 month ahead of what it should be in JS, , so this 2 years 4 months is actually 2 years 5 months.... and there's your problem.

You could avoid a large chunk of this code by simply having:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(yourdatetimefield) ...
```

for your query, then output that to JS directly:

```
oldDate = new Date(<?php echo $timestamp ?>000);
// '000' in there to make it a JS-style milliseconds timestamp
```